# My sql query for combining two column data

Tags: mysql

I have one table named time slot in that I have start time and end time.start time and end time is differ by 3hrs
Ex. 8am-11am  give me a query to display start time and end time separeted by '-' and it should as time slot label

Comment: What exacly you want?

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function, which concatenates strings:

```
SELECT CONCAT(starttime,'-', endtime) from myTable
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response  it is working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select CONCAT_WS('-', start_time, end_time) as 'Time Slot' from your_table
```

`CONCAT_WS` function will append n number of comma separated strings by `-` separator. You don't need to write `-` multiple times unlike `CONCAT` function.

Give it a try, this should work.

Comment: Dear sir, Thank you for your quick response and it is working as per my requirment